# I have a "main.js:200 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')" when opening for second time a modal

Tags: javascript

The first time I click on an image, the modal is correctly loaded, but when I close it and open it again, I have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')

This is my HTML code:

```
        <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog" id="modalDialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header" id="modalHeader">
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" id="btnClose" onclick="CloseModal()" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-body px-0" data-bs-interval="false" id="@Model.FirstOrDefault().getNumeroEntrega()">
                    <div id="C_@Model.FirstOrDefault().getNumeroEntrega()" class="carousel slide carousel-dark" data-bs-interval="false">
                            <div id="Entrega_@Model.FirstOrDefault().getNumeroEntrega()" class="carousel-inner" data-bs-interval="false">
                                <!--Creacion del carousel con imagenes-->
                                <!--Fin del carousel-->
                        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#C_@Model.FirstOrDefault().getNumeroEntrega()" data-bs-slide="prev">
                                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                                </button>
                                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#C_@Model.FirstOrDefault().getNumeroEntrega()" data-bs-slide="next">
                                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this my Javascript:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
 while (z < result.length) {
                    var carusel = document.getElementById("Entrega_" + entrega);
                    if (z == 0) {
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-item active');
                        let btn = document.createElement('button');
                        btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary mt-3');
                        btn.textContent = "Descargar Imágen";
                        let im = document.createElement('i');
                        im.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-download mx-2');
                        btn.appendChild(im);

                        div.appendChild(btn);
                        var img = document.createElement("img");
                        img.setAttribute('class', 'img-responsive img-fluid');
                        img.setAttribute('id', "img01")
                        //img.setAttribute('src', srcImg)
                        div.appendChild(img);
                        img.setAttribute('src', result[z].path);
                        carusel.appendChild(div);
                        z++;
                    }
                    else {
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-item');
                        let btn = document.createElement('button');
                        btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');
                        btn.textContent = "Descargar Imágen";
                        let im = document.createElement('i');
                        im.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-download mx-2');
                        btn.appendChild(im);
                        div.appendChild(btn);
                        var img = document.createElement('img');
                        img.setAttribute('class', 'img-responsive img-fluid');
                        img.setAttribute('id', "img01")
                        div.appendChild(img);
                        img.setAttribute('src', result[z].path);
                        carusel.appendChild(div);
                        z++;
                    }
                }

//'X' button onclick function

function CloseModal() {
    let modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    modal.style.display = "none";
    modal.remove();
}
```

This happened after removing a foreach loop in the HTML code, only for accessing the model values, and now I'm using `@Model.FirstOrDefault.getNumero()` and I have it correctly.  I think this is okey but I don't know why I have that error.

The error is in the first `carusel.appendChild(div)`, when `z == 0`

Comment: So that means it could not find the element. `var carusel = document.getElementById("Entrega_" + entrega); console.log(entrega , carusel);`

Comment: The **first** time it can find the element `console.log(entrega, carusel)` = `'11111, <div id clas...>'`. But the **second** time is `console.log(entrega, carusel)` = `'11111, null'`

Comment: Well you remove the element from the DOM when you close it.... Is that your problem?

Comment: It's worth to create the `carousel modal` with Javascript when I click on a image?